# How to know where the error in code is

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Today, I have made an error that frustrated me for hours to see what was wrong, with the Google App Engine SDK. But, what was wrong with my code was a syntax error (really silly).

Here is my incorrect code:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage), debug=True)
```

Instead of:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

My question is: when a similar error occurs again, I don't know **how to know** where error is. When I use localhost, I just receive a "Server fault". When I post to the Google App Engine, I just receive:

> Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not
>   complete your request. If the problem persists, please report your
>   problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

Whet I view the log in Google App Engine, it still says nothing about the error. So, how can I prevent some form of this problem in the future, if nothing show me where things are  wrong in my code?

Comment: You logs suppose to have the exact location for this type of errors, please post your logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that you can check for *syntax errors* in your code is simply by running the file like a normal python program. In your case, it would have given something like:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage), debug=True)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If there aren't any errors in the syntax, it will probably give you some error about not finding appengine specific modules. But it will always check the syntax first.

This obviously won't work for all types of errors, but it's a good place to start.

However, I'm not really sure why you would need to do this in the first place. When I try to visit a local app in a browser (that has an error), I get a debug page with plenty of information about that error.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an IDE such as Eclipse with PyDev it will highlight syntax errors like that for you.